# Dojo-DataGrid :: How to dynamically fetch values as options for a select box in Dojo DataGrid

Tags: select, datagrid, dojo

I have a Dojo-DataGrid which is programatically populated as below :

```
var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: "json/gaskets.json" });
var layout= [
                { field: "description", width: "auto", name: "Tier/Description", editable:true },
                { field: "billingMethod", width: "auto", name: "Billing Method", editable: true,
                    type: dojox.grid.cells.Select, options: [ '0', '1' ]  },
                { field: "offeringComponents", width: "auto", name: "Offering Component", editable: true,
                    type: dojox.grid.cells.Select, options: [ '0', '1' ] },
                { field: "serviceActivity", width: "auto", name: "Service Activity", editable: true,
                    type: dojox.grid.cells.Select, options: [ '0', '1' ] },
                { field: "hours", width: "auto", name: "Hours" },
                { field: "rate", width: "auto", name: "Rate <br/> (EUR)" },
                { field: "cost", width: "auto", name: "Cost <br/> (EUR)" },
                { field: "price", width: "auto", name: "Price <br/> (EUR)" },
                { field: "gvn", width: "auto", name: "Gvn" }
            ];

            grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                query: { description: '*' },
                store: jsonStore,
                structure: layout,
                rowsPerPage: 20
            }, 'gridNode');
```

The options for the field billingMethod (Currently defined as dojox.grid.cells.Select) are hard coded right now, but I would like to get those values dynamically from the backend as JSON. But dojox.grid.cells.Select currently(I am using Dojo 1.5) does not have a option to define a "store".

I am trying to use dijit.form.FilteringSelect, but this needs a id(of a Div) for its constructor and I cannot specify one as this select box has to go with in the grid, rather than a separate DIV.

Thanks
Sandeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer works fine, the issue is that in the combo the user can select A, but once the combo lose the focus, the value 1 will be shown. Some months ago I had the same problem, and I got a solution from KGF on #dojo. The idea is to have a formatter on the cell that just creates a SPAN element, and then it invokes a query over the store to get the label of the selected element and put it on the SPAN. I modified your example to get that working.

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.cells.dijit");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");

dojo.require('dojox.grid.cells.dijit');
dojo.require('dijit.form.FilteringSelect');

var grid;
var jsonStore;

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            "identifier": "identify",
            "label": "description",
            "items": [
                {
                "identify": 123,
                "description": "Project Manager"},
            {
                "identify": 234,
                "description": "Developer"},
            {
                "identify": 536,
                "description": "Developer",
                "billingMethod":2}
            ]
        }
    });

    var myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data: {
            identifier: 'value',
            label: 'name',
            items: [{
                value: 1,
                name: 'A',
                label: 'A'},
            {
                value: 2,
                name: 'B',
                label: 'B'},
            {
                value: 3,
                name: 'C',
                label: 'C'}]
        }
    });

      //[kgf] callback referenced by formatter for FilteringSelect cell
      function displayValue(nodeId, store, attr, item) {
        if (item != null) { //if it's null, it wasn't found!
          dojo.byId(nodeId).innerHTML = store.getValue(item, attr);
        }
      }

    var layout = [
        {
        field: "identify",
        width: "auto",
        name: "Id 2 Hide",
        hidden: true},
    {
        field: "description",
        width: "auto",
        name: "Tier/Description",
        editable: true},
    {
        field: 'billingMethod',
        name: 'Billing Method',
        editable: true,
        required: true,
        width: '150px',
        type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
        widgetClass: dijit.form.FilteringSelect,
        widgetProps: {
            store: myStore
        },
        formatter: function(data, rowIndex) { //[kgf]
            //alert("data "+data)
                var genId = 'title' + rowIndex;
            var store = this.widgetProps.store;
            var attr = "label";

            setTimeout(function() {
                store.fetchItemByIdentity({
                    identity: data,
                    onItem: dojo.partial(displayValue, genId, store, attr)
                });
                }, 50);
            //for now return a span with a predetermined id for us to populate.
            return '<span id="' + genId + '"></span>';
        }    
    }
    ];

    grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        query: {
            description: '*'
        },
        store: jsonStore,
        singleClickEdit: true,
        structure: layout,
        rowsPerPage: 20
    }, 'gridNode');

    grid.startup();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for perfecting the code, but I noticed that the formatter function removes the element which was set as default(Coming from jsonStore) in my example and displays a blank. How can we fix this? Please see below for updated code with ur formatter.
** [Updated Code With No default displayed](http://jsfiddle.net/R64bE/12/) **
I gave a default of "sample" for column **Billing Method**, but it gets overridden by the formatter I guess.

Comment: Well, the issue here is that "Sample" is not in the values accepted by the combo, and therefore the formatter fails to find it on the store and it can not set it on the SPAN. I've made a modification so if the item is not found, but there is a value, it shows the value. You can see it on http://jsfiddle.net/zsvvt/4/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Works perfectly. Quick question, when I click on default value in the 1st row under billing method column, the value displayed vanishes and presents me with a filtering select. Is there anyway I can retain the value and show it until user selects a new value from the drop down list.

Comment: I'm not an expert at all, but I don't think it's possible, since when you click the Grid replaces the content of the cell with a combo, so what you are seeing in the cell is not an empty cell, but an empty combo(it will be filled when you select a value). I don't know if a FilteringSelect has an EmptyValue or something like that to indicate "Select one method". If so, I would work it that way.

Comment: I had to tweak this code to make it working. Required to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure this out..Incase someone wants to implement same kind of stuff using DOJO Datagrid+FilteringSelect.

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/R64bE/2/)

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.cells.dijit");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");

dojo.require('dojox.grid.cells.dijit');
dojo.require('dijit.form.FilteringSelect');

var grid;
var jsonStore;

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            "identifier": "identify",
            "label": "description",
            "items": [
                {
                "identify": 123,
                "description": "Project Manager"},
            {
                "identify": 234,
                "description": "Developer"},
            {
                "identify": 536,
                "description": "Developer"}
            ]
        }
    });

    var myStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data: {
            identifier: 'value',
            label: 'name',
            items: [{
                value: 1,
                name: 'A',
                label: 'A'},
            {
                value: 2,
                name: 'B',
                label: 'Y'},
            {
                value: 3,
                name: 'C',
                label: 'C'}]
        }
    });


    var layout = [
        {
        field: "identify",
        width: "auto",
        name: "Id 2 Hide",
        hidden: true},
    {
        field: "description",
        width: "auto",
        name: "Tier/Description",
        editable: true},
    {
        field: 'billingMethod',
        name: 'Billing Method',
        editable: true,
        required: true,
        width: '150px',
        type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
        widgetClass: dijit.form.FilteringSelect,
        widgetProps: {
            store: myStore
        }}
    ];

    grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        query: {
            description: '*'
        },
        store: jsonStore,
        singleClickEdit: true,
        structure: layout,
        rowsPerPage: 20
    }, 'gridNode');

    grid.startup();

});
```