# dojo enchancedGrid dynamacally set editable false on specific cell doesnt make a change

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I have my datagrid which I take the actuall row I click on and then loop it through, I get the values I want and change editable true to false. I found this `render()` function that I could not get to work. I tried many ways but I havent succedded yes. So my qestion is: when I change the editable to false on a specific cell how to I tell the grid to notice the change?

Thanks in advance

```
    var theStructure = grid.structure;
    var allCells = theStructure[0].cells;
    var _checker = 0;

    for(allItems in allCells) {
      if(_checker == 0) {
        allCells[3].editable = false;
        grid.render();
        _checker = 1;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct API. I searched a lot and here are the two links which helped me achieve it in the end:

Last post on http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-grid-DataGrid-disable-cell-editing-on-specific-rows-td3987523.html

the correct answer from [Dojo-DataGrid :: How to dynamically fetch values as options for a select box in Dojo DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734141/dojo-datagrid-how-to-dynamically-fetch-values-as-options-for-a-select-box-in)

Please note that the first link is to have a method which needs to be called for rows,columns you want not to be editable but once you click on a column which is un-editable, it leaves ... and to fix that we need to hit the corresponding store of the field and display it using HTML span element which is done through the second link.

Try these, it should work as it worked for me. If not working, let us know the issue.

Comment: It is not working for me. My grid structure will always have editable:false for all the fields. Based on condition, I would like to make cell editable not entire structure field (column).